# Manage friendship with parse

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

i'm trying to manage friendship using parse.com but i have some trouble because i usually use sql db. In parse i've a tab "user" and i'm using a column type relation that point to the same tab user. Is it correct?

Now i'm trying to add friend but appear this error:post 400 (Bad Request);

```
     var Models = {};

     Models.utenti = new Usercollection();
     Models.utenti.fetch({
       success: function(object) {
           console.log(object);
       },
       error: function(amici, error) {

       }
    }); 

    var amico=Models.utenti.get("xj3QLLYy07");        
    var user = Parse.User.current();
    var relation = user.relation("amici");
    relation.add(amico);
    user.save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to make relation to the same table (User relation to User).
If you want to add new user to relation of other user you can do it this way:

```
var curUser = Parse.User.current();

var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.equalTo("objectId", "userId_you_want_to_add"); //xj3QLLYy07

//find the user you want to add
userQuery.first().then
(
    function(userToAdd)
    {
        var relation = curUser.relation("amici");

            //add user to relation
        relation.add(userToAdd);
        curUser.save();
    },
    function(error)
    {
        console.log("error: " + error.message);
    }
);
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: if i add  user1 in the relation column amici of user2 must i add in otherway,user 2 in relation column of user1?

Comment: it depends on what you want to do. If it is possible to user1 be a friend of user2 without the necessity of user2 to be a friend of user one (in other words "one way" friendship) then you don't have to update user2. in this case user1 is friend of usre2, user2 is not friend of user1. If you want that user2 would be a friend of user1 you have to add user1 to user2 relation field. Better practice is to create another table (collection) in which there are 2 user columns (pointer to User), this way you can establish friendships.